# Material, Texture and Light interaction

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, lighting

I have written a simple 3D model viewer (using OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL), which can load and render U3D models (either standalone, or from inside a PDF). It can basically render all the different meshes, draw them either by vertex color, texture or material and light them accordingly.

However I haven't quite figured out what is the "expected way" of combining materials and textures. I have seen tutorials which light objects that have materials (with diffuse/specular/ambient components and a factor for opacity and shininess), and other tutorials which use textures and light them, but I haven't found any good resources on what the expected behaviour is when they are combined (ie the mesh has a material and one or more texture layers).

Also according to the spec for the U3D file format in their "LitTextureShader" description I support 4 different blend functions that determine how one texture layer is combined with the result from the previous ones:

```
// Multiply     
blended = current * previous;  
// Add  
blended = clamp(current + previous, 0.0, 1.0);  
// Replace  
blended = current;  
// Blend  
blended = mix( previous , current, current.a );
```

Originally I thought this is just applied between texture layers, but when I look at the models in Adobe Reader, those blend operations seem to be applied also between texture and material sometimes as well, but the result is never what I would expect it to be (and looks very different from my result), so I assumed that there is some underlying part that I didn't fully understand.

For my tests I created a mesh made of one single triangle, a red material, and two checkerboard textures:
[image: CheckerBoard 1]
 and 
[image: CheckerBoard 2]

My fragment shader generally looks like this (shortened and simplified, not taking specular or emmissive light into consideration):

```
// uniforms, lights etc
// ...

// material input
flat in vec4   matDiffuse;
flat in float  matOpacity;
// ...

// globals
vec3 accumulatedLight = vec3(0.0);  
vec4 currAmbientColor = vec4(0.0);
vec4 currDiffuseColor = vec4(0.0);
float currOpacity = 1.0;
// ...

// lighting
void AddLightOutput()
{
    // add ambient
    vec3 ambientTerm = vec3(0.0);
    if( Lights.enableAmbient == 1 )
    {
        ambientTerm = (vec3(currAmbientColor) * vec3(Lights.ambientIntensity));
    }

    // add diffuse and specular
    vec3 diffuseTerm = vec3(0.0);
    for( int index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_LIGHTS; index++ )
    {
        // calculate ...
        diffuseTerm += vec3(lgt.diffuse) * lightDot * attenuation;

        // specular (disregard for now)
        // ...
    }

    // add up results results
    accumulatedLight = ambientTerm + (diffuseTerm * vec3(currDiffuseColor));
}

void main()
{
    // set up colors and opacity
    currDiffuseColor = texture(texSampler0, vertTexCoord0) * vec4( vec3(texIntensity0), 1.0 );
    currOpacity = matOpacity;

    // apply material-texture interaction ?
    // ??

    // iterate all lights
    AddLightOutput();

    // set result color
    resultColor = vec4(accumulatedLight, currOpacity);
}
```

[Side question: I keep all the materials in a texture buffer object, and the vertex shader picks the material based on a uniform, and passes it down to fragment shader (flat out/in) - not sure if that is a good idea (some of the models I loaded had several hundred -or even well over a thousand- materials, that's why I tried it this way)?]

So based on the above shader, I tried two cases, one where a single texture (blue-green checkerboard) is combined with a red material, and the texture blending in the first case is set to "multiply" and in the second to "add" (neither texture nor material set to be translucent)

My shader:

```
// add base color info
currDiffuseColor = texture(texSampler0, vertTexCoord0) * vec4( vec3(texIntensity0), 1.0 );

// modify color according to blend factors
currOpacity = matOpacity * currDiffuseColor.a;
currDiffuseColor = matDiffuse * currDiffuseColor;
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

This made me believe that I am on the right track and the material and texture should both be operated on to get the correct result, but then the "add" shader:

```
// add base color info
currDiffuseColor = texture(texSampler0, vertTexCoord0) * vec4( vec3(texIntensity0), 1.0 );

// modify color according to blend factors
currOpacity = matOpacity;
currDiffuseColor = vec4( clamp(matDiffuse + currDiffuseColor, 0.0, 1.0).rgb, currDiffuseColor.a );
```

and the result:

[image: Valid XHTML]

which made me think the material shouldn't affect it. So I also tried a case of two textures (those checkerboards, which have no transparency btw) which should be added to each other:

```
// set up colors and opacity
currDiffuseColor = texture(texSampler0, vertTexCoord0) * vec4( vec3(texIntensity0), 1.0 );
vec4 texLayer1 = texture(texSampler1, vertTexCoord1) * vec4( vec3(texIntensity1), 1.0 );
currDiffuseColor = vec4( clamp(currDiffuseColor + texLayer1, 0.0, 1.0).rgb, texLayer1.a );
```

[image: Result Comparison]

My code adds it together, whereas Adobe Reader just seems to show texture layer 0.

Also for example if I set the U3D to make the texture layer transparent (and use the blending constant), Adobe gives me this:

[image: Valid XHTML]
 
However Adobe doesn't seem to take into consideration the value of that blending constant, so again I have different results.

So all those results leave me confused as in how "normally" textures and materials are supposed to influence each other. Essentially the result doesn't necessarily have to be exactly the same as Adobe, but I would like to have predictable results, so that someone making a model can know what to expect based on "typical behaviour" for modelling or rendering software.

If I have material opacity and texture opacity will they be multiplied on top of each other? Are only texture layers supposed to be blend/add/multiply/replace each other, or also to interact with the material? Is the material the only factor for the lighting? Or should the light be calculated on the texture(s)? To me it just seems the results from Adobe are inconsistent, but it might just be me lacking some understanding.

For reference I have uploaded the example PDFs that I have created to this zip: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drabeck/stackoverflow/TestPDF3Ds.zip - it also contains the screenshots produced from my app, and also the text files (IDTF) I used to create the U3D (and from that the PDF).